# UITableView reusable custom cells show wrong content in subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableViewController subclass in which I populate the UITableView with data as follows:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("kundeCell") as! KundeCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    let kunde = self.kundenAuszutragen[indexPath.row]

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.kunde = kunde

    cell.allowsSwypeRight = (self.zahlungenImQuartalVonKunde[kunde] == nil) // Abkassieren
    cell.allowsSwypeLeft = self.state == .Austragen                         // Austragen

    cell.abkassierButton.titleAbkassierLabel.showsTextFilled = self.zahlungenImQuartalVonKunde[kunde] != nil

    return cell
}
```

This works fine, it looks like that:
[image: iOS Simulator with App running]

The upper text is a UILabel, the bottom text is from a UIButton (in both cases the default ones). The € sign at the right is a custom UIButton with a subview of a custom UILabel that displays the € with a stroke effect, here's the relevant code of the custom UIButton, that is called when the button is initted:

```
private func handleInit()
{
    // titleAbkassierLabel is the custom UILabel with the stroke
    self.titleAbkassierLabel = AbkassierLabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height))
    self.titleAbkassierLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(self.titleAbkassierLabelFontSize)
    self.titleAbkassierLabel.text = self.titleText
    self.titleAbkassierLabel.textColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.titleAbkassierLabel.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.addSubview(self.titleAbkassierLabel)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Now when I set the € sign of a cell to be filled, it looks like that:[image: my custom UITableViewCell with the € sign filled]

The following code is then called in the UIButton subclass:

```
self.titleAbkassierLabel.showsTextFilled = true

// which then again comes to: (in the titleAbkassierLabel - property)
var showsTextFilled: Bool = true {  
    didSet
    {
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

So okay, this cell is "highlighted" with the filled €. But if I then scroll down, other cells are highlighted as well (of course because the first cell is reused, by why does it show the right text (in the labels at the left) but not the right € sign? The cells that shouldn't be highlighted even look different from the others:
[image: compare it to the other cell, the € seems to be thicker]
(compare it to the other cell, the € seems to be thicker)

So it looks thicker, but if I look in ViewDebugger, I see that there's just one custom button and one custom € - label:
[image]

If you need more information, just comment. Thank you very much and I hope you understand the problem despite the German property names/etc.!

EDIT: My Cell delegate:

```
protocol AustragenAbkassierenDelegate
{
    // Kunde bearbeiten
    func setKundeAusgetragen(kunde: Kunde, animated: Bool) -> Bool
    func setKundeAbkassiert(kunde: Kunde, createZahlung: Bool, endAction: (() -> Void)?) -> UIAlertController?

    func getNextKundeAfterKunde(kunde: Kunde) -> Kunde?

    func showKundeDetailVCWithKunde(kunde: Kunde)

    func showAlertController(alert: UIAlertController!, completionHandler: (() -> Void)?)
}
```

But I don't think this has something to do with the issue. It is just to notify the delegate (here the TableViewController) when something has changed.

Comment: Do you call `handleInit` again if you set `showsTextFilled`? What happens if you set that property?

Comment: no, handleInit is just called in initWithCoder and initWithFrame of my UIButton subclass, which I set from the storyboard. As you can see, if you set showsTextFilled, the label calls setNeedsDisplay on itself to redraw its content in `drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) `

Comment: you are setting the new text in cellforRowAtIndexPath but not if the Euro Sign is filled or not. That might be the reason why the text ist correct but the button not

Comment: I do: `cell.abkassierButton.titleAbkassierLabel.showsTextFilled = self.zahlungenImQuartalVonKunde[kunde] != nil` in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: In your KundeCell, do you implement prepareForReuse? It seems there is some portion of your button/label initialization that needs to be done every time but is only getting done once.

Comment: no, I don't, but this might be the solution. When is this method be called? Before cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: what does your cell.delegate looks like ?

Comment: 1) if I set the titleAbkassierLabel.showsTextFilled to false in prepareForReuse, it's the same problem

Comment: When you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, it returns either a brand new cell or reuses an old one. If it returns you an old one, it will call prepareForReuse on that cell before returning it.

Comment: 2) see above for the delegate

Comment: When you set showsTextFilled, you are calling code that might be part of the problem. Instead, try rebuilding the titleAbkassierLabel from scratch. You could call your handleInit from prepareForReuse except that you don't want to keep adding subviews.

Comment: Another thought, what is zahlungenImQuartalVonKunde and how is it updated when user taps a button?

Comment: @MikeTaverne your first thought with recreating the label worked. Thank you! Please create a regular answer for this question, so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebuilding the titleAbkassierLabel from scratch in your cell's prepareForReuse method.